# How to make multiple divs appear one after the other using javascript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm trying to animate a chat. Every time the user clicks on the input field or "send" icon, I want the chat bubbles to appear one after the other. This is my part of my code so far. Right now, they all have "display: none." The picture below shows them without it.

```
 <div class="messages">
            <div class="message" id="msg1" style="display: none;">Hi! I'm looking for an old friend. She attended Martin Grove a few years ago.</div>
            <div class="message" id="msg2" style="display: none;">Her name is Sam.<br>
                <i>*insert pic of Sam and MC*</i></div>
            <div class="message" id="msg3" style="display: none;">Did you know her or her last name by any chance? </div>
            <div id="msg4" class="message-teacher" style="display: none;">Hello there!</div>
            <div class="message-teacher" id="msg5" style="display: none;">Unfortunately, I did not have the pleasure of teaching Sam. Her last name and whereabouts are a mystery to me as well. </div>
            <div class="message-teacher" id="msg6" style="display: none;">However, I do know she was in the photography club. I always saw her carrying a camera, always taking pictures. </div>
            <div class="message-teacher" id="msg7" style="display: none;">In fact, I believe she won a contest for one of them. </div>
            <div class="message-teacher" id="msg8" style="display: none;">She’s a super talented girl!</div>
            <div class="message-teacher" id="msg9" style="display: none;">Best of luck on your search. I hope you two are reunited soon!</div>
        </div>

        <div class="input">
            <div class="plus-icon" style="font-size: 25px; color: #2A84FF; margin: auto;">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="subinput" style="font-size: 25px; color: #2A84FF; margin: auto;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="|" />
                <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="btn" style="font-size: 23px; color: #2A84FF; margin: auto;"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></div>
        </div>
```

[image: chat window]

Answer (score 1):

I would query for the required elements, create an array out of it, and `shift()` (aka remove the first element of the array - or you can use `pop()` to remove the last element, depending on your needs). When you pop or shift an element from an array, those functions return the removed element and we can remove the CSS class that hides those elements in the DOM.

```js
const myHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("invisible");
const HTMLElementsArr = [...myHTMLCollection];

function showMessage() {
if (HTMLElementsArr.length > 0) {
    HTMLElementsArr.shift().classList.remove('invisible');
}
}
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="invisible">Some text 1 click</p>
<p class="invisible">Some text 2 clicks</p>
<p class="invisible">Some text 3 clicks</p>

<button onClick="showMessage()">Show a message</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want each bubble to appear every time the button is clicked

Comment: ok, adapting the example with a button to trigger that

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. The code you have shows the messages appearing all at once, but timed. I want one message to show after each click. So, if it's the second message, the user needs to click the button twice to see it. Or three clicks to see the third message.